# How can run yarn cammand on visual studio code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Yarn successfully installed on my laptop. But every time I try to run yarn command in VS code, its say, `'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

[image]

Answer (score 16):

if yarn not working but npm doing ok in your vs code terminal. Then go to search of window and search for window powercell and run it using run as administrator and write code in number 2 and 3 and make the option yes

1. Open Powershell and run as administrator
2. Get-ExecutionPolicy
3. Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestrict (if you want for local user) -Scope CurrentUser
4. Restart the system

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar error. I have just installed `npm` and `yarn`. When I opened my project using VS Code and tried to run `yarn install` the terminal said that the file "blabla\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1" were not digitally signed. The same happened when I tried to run `yarn --version`, which worked fine in Git Bash Terminal. To solve this, I just removed the file yarn.ps1 stated above, and everything worked fine.

Comment: Give this man a medal! So simple, so useful!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install yarn in visual studio code then simply use these steps or use official yarn documentation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-yarn

You will redirect to official way to install yarn.

Step 1 - you have vs code install in your system, if don't have then go to vs code download page and download for your operating system.

Step 2 - open vs code terminal and run this command - ext install gamunu.vscode-yarn

Download the latest .vsix release file from the GitHub repository and install it from the command line

code --install-extension vscode-yarn-*.*.*.vsix
or from within VS Code by launching Quick Open and running the Install from VSIX... command.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the PowerShell as an administrator.
2. Install Yarn by running the following command:

`npm install --global yarn`

3. Verify the Yarn installation with:

`yarn --version`

Answer (score 0):

you just install yarn via gitbash terminal, it works for me